# CSS3 Text Won't Vertically Align

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a footer for my website but the text inside the footer is displaying half in and half out of the footer div. I attempted to correct it using all the methods suggested in [How do I vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css) and searched other ideas on the internet but none worked (unless I messed up applying them to my code). Here's my code.
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xyqgpr14/2/

Footer html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-bottom" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Style CSS:

```
.navbar-bottom {
    background-color: #222;
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
    height: 50px;
    color: #777;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Bootstrap, hence a default margin or padding is present in the nav.

Add this to the css:

```
.navbar-bottom * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

This will remove any margin/padding in the child divs of nav.

Here is the updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xyqgpr14/3/

Comment: Thank you, this worked, I didn't know that CSS had ' * ', and changing the individuals' margin and padding did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The latest method involves:

```
.container {
   position:relative;
}

h1 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Or something similar.

Comment: This solution worked in JSFiddle but when I copied it EXACTLY to my website the footer moved to the middle of the webpage and messed up the entire web page.

Comment: Try adding margin: 0 auto; to your nav element.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple methods you can use. Here're the latest methods:

```
.navbar-bottom {
    background-color: #222;
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
    height: 50px;
    color: #777;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar-bottom .container {
   position:relative;
}

.navbar-bottom h1 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Or

```
.navbar-bottom {
    background-color: #222;
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
    height: 50px;
    color: #777;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar-bottom .container {
    display: table;
}

.navbar-bottom h1 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Ian D.** already said about second one, you can try mine though! I think that did not work since you copied his code EXACTLY he wrote. Please target specific element in CSS otherwise that could overwrite other code from above. My code can be copied EXACTLY as it is! Both of them work fine. Just simply copy any of them to your jsfiddle and see the impact. :)